# Google Cloud IoT Core Node.js Client: How to get lastHeartbeatTime of a device in a google cloud function?

Tags: google-cloud-iot

I use the **DeviceManagerClient.listDevices** function of the 2.1.1 API in cloud functions
and it works right, apart from the fact that most of the properties of the got **IDevice**s are null.
The **id**, **numId**, and **metadata** properties are not null but everything else inclusive **lastHeartbeatTime**.
How can I get **lastHeartbeatTime** of a device from a cloud function using the Node.js API?

Best regards,
Árpád

Comment: What does the exact code of your listDevices API call look like?  Look at the underlying API call here ... https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/reference/cloudiot/rest/v1/projects.locations.registries.devices/list

Look at the "fieldMask".  It is up to YOUR API call to declare what you want returned.  It looks like lastHeartbeatTime is not in the default set.

Comment: Thank you Kolban, sorry for the late answer. I overlooked the "fieldMask" property. But I have another problem: how to get the fully qualified name of "lastHeartbeatTime"? "lastHeartbeatTime" and "google.cloud.iot.v1.IDevice.lastHeartbeatTime" are invalid.

Comment: I think this is the answer ... https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-iot/issues/178

Looks like it should be "last_heartbeat_time"

Please also post an update to the Github issue saying that you got bit by the poor documentation too.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Kolban for your answer!

This is a usage example:

```
const listDevicesResponse = await iotClient.listDevices({
  parent: iotClient.registryPath(process.env.GCLOUD_PROJECT!, CLOUD_REGION, REGISTRY_ID),
  fieldMask: {paths: ['last_heartbeat_time']}
  // For a full list of fieldMask paths see https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-iot/issues/178#issuecomment-580999577
});
const devices = listDevicesResponse[0];
for(const device of devices) {
  if (devices === null) continue;
  functions.logger.info(`device.id:${device.id}, device.lastHeartbeatTime?.seconds:${device.lastHeartbeatTime?.seconds}`);
}
```